# Nodes not joining Cassandra Cluster 2.1.0

Tags: exception, cassandra, cluster-computing

I have two fedora linux servers connected with a switch.
On 192.168.5.1 Machine One, cassandra.yaml-

```
- seeds: "192.168.5.1"
listen_address: 192.168.5.1
rpc_address: 192.168.5.1
```

On 192.168.5.2 Machine Two, cassandra.yaml -

```
- seeds: "192.168.5.1"
listen_address: 192.168.5.2
rpc_address: 192.168.5.2
```

Cassandra starts on Machine One fine.
Start Cassandra on Machine Two fails with following error  -

```
ERROR [main] 2014-10-14 22:42:19,272 CassandraDaemon.java:474 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1200) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:451) ~[apache-
```

Both machines are connected via a Switch and i can ping each other by IP Address.
netstat -nr on Machine1 -

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp0s45f8u2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp0s45f8u2
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 em1
```

netstat -nr on Machine2 -

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 em1
```

Comment: Do you have firewalls running?

Comment: Seems very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183989/exception-encountered-during-startup-unable-to-gossip-with-any-seeds/

Comment: I agree it is probably firewall issue, i will test and update. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It was firewall issue, once i opened all the required ports, both nodes are joining the cluster fine. Thanks to both of you.